# My Javascript runs in Chrome, Not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, console

I've run the following code in the console in chrome and it works just fine. When I attempt to run in the firebug console and scroll to the trigger point at the bottom of the page nothing happens. Can anyone help ID why this isn't working in firefox?

```
CartSummaryOverlay = {
  activate: document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight * 0.9,
  limit: 0,
  totalItems: parseInt(jQuery('span.cart-total-qty').text()),
  loadSummary: function(){
      if (CartSummaryOverlay.totalItems > 0) {  
        jQuery.get("/checkout/cart", function(html){
          CartSummaryOverlay.total = jQuery("td.total span.price span", html).text();
          CartSummaryOverlay.CreateOverlayBackground();
          CartSummaryOverlay.RemoveOverlayBackground();
        });
      } else {
        CartSummaryOverlay.total =  "0";
        CartSummaryOverlay.CreateOverlayBackground();
        CartSummaryOverlay.RemoveOverlayBackground();
      }
  },
  CreateOverlayBackground: function(){
    $overlay = jQuery("<div id='overlay' style='background-color: #000; opacity: .85; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1000; color: white; text-align: center; font-size: 200%;'></div>");
    $overlay.html('<div style="position: fixed; top: 40%; left: 38%;">Number of Items in Cart: '+CartSummaryOverlay.totalItems+'<br>Total: '+CartSummaryOverlay.total+'</div><div id="close_overlay"><a id="closing_tag" style="top: 35%; right: 38%; color: white; position: fixed; font-size: 50%;">X</a></div>');
    jQuery("body").append($overlay);
  },
  pageScroll: function(){
    var current_height = document.body.scrollTop + document.body.clientHeight;
    if (current_height >= CartSummaryOverlay.activate && CartSummaryOverlay.limit === 0) {
      CartSummaryOverlay.loadSummary();
      CartSummaryOverlay.limit += 1;
    }
  },
  RemoveOverlayBackground: function(){
    // setTimeout(function(){
      jQuery('#closing_tag').click(function(){
      jQuery("#overlay").remove();
      CartSummaryOverlay.limit = 0;
      });
  }
}


window.onscroll = CartSummaryOverlay.pageScroll;
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the web console?

Comment: I did not get any errors as far as I can tell.

Comment: Webkit and Gecko do use different elements for attaching the scroll bar, one uses `<body>` and the other `<html>`, and you seem to be using strange selectors when you have jQuery, for instance `document.body.parentNode` would most likely be the `document.documentElement` or in jQuery just `$('html')` ?

Comment: I've changed the selectors around (all to jquery) and am still getting the same issue. It seems to work on some but not all pages in FF and works wherever in chrome (granted its built to work for one specific page so it doesn't do much for me on random pages.)

Comment: It appears to be this line.
var current_height = jQuery('body')[0].scrollTop + jQuery('body')[0].clientHeight;
it returns the same value in firefox but is doing what I want in chrome.

Comment: oh yeah, don't use the [0] after the jQuery('body').